# Switching default to video while uploading photos in iPhone browser

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, video, safari

When we put a file tag to upload a `file in HTML` and try to render it in `iPhone browser`, `iOS` provides 2 options: `'Take Photo or Video'` and `'Choose Existing'`.

When we select `'Take Photo or Video'`, camera gets opened and by default its in `'Photo'` mode. Can we set it to `'Video' mode` via `html/js` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `accept="video/*"` on the `input` element. This will remove the option to capture a photo as well as the option to select a photo from the Photo Library.

- http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/07-accept.html